# Regexp to add a string after found a regexp in a file

Tags: regex, replace, emacs

At the beginning i was looking for an Emacs command, I found `query-replace-regexp` but I didn't find how to solve my problem with this command.
I m looking for replace a string by another one in a file.

I want to replace this:

> container random1-string {

by this:

> container random1-string {
>
> string:string-string 0;

or this:

> container 1-string {

by this:

> container 1-string {
>
> string:string-string 0;

or this:

> container string-24 {

by this:

> container string-24 {
>
> string:string-string 0;

`random1-string` is a random string.
I'm looking for a recursive command. I have to change 400 nodes.
I can use every linux command.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to provide you an answer. Where is `string:string-string 0;` coming from for example? [Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, if `random1-string` is variable, can you post more examples of what this variable might look like? Is there a common format?

Comment: What is the regexp you wish to match? Or can you describe the rules in English? Is it each and every instance of a line `container foo {` where `foo` could be any symbol? If it needs to be more restrictive, what are the constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your random-string does not have a specific pattern it will difficult to use a regex to replace it efficiently.

What you could do, is list up the variable name that you want to change in a file (**strings_list.in**)

```
random1-string
random2-string
random3-string
```

and then loop on the file and change your source file in the following way:

```
for v in `cat strings_list.in`;
do
    sed -i "s/container\s+$v\{/container $v\{\nstring:string-string 0;/g" file_to_edit;
done;
```

**Take a backup of your file before any operation.**

If your random string is actually a **variable**, then you can use the following regex in your sed command to process the file, with a back reference to it:

```
sed -i "s/container\s+([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\s*\{/container \1 \{\nstring:string-string 0;/g" file_to_edit;
```

Comment: i got an error  : sed: -e expression # 1, character 85: Previous regular expression invalid

Comment: sed -i "s/container\s+([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\s*\{/container \1 {\nstring:string-string 0;/g" myfile.txt;

Comment: i also try :cat myfile.txt | sed -i "s/container\s+$v\{/container $v\{\nstring:string-string 0;/g" myfile.txt;
sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 56: Échec du pairage de \{

Comment: af a backslash before the bracket `{` in the second part of the sed command, also you will have to change the regex of the first part if your variable can start by some digits